# Textbox Enabled True False

Tags: vb.net

This is code am trying to solve

```
        Dim i As Integer
    i = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        TextBox10.Enabled = False
        TextBox25.Enabled = False
        TextBox30.Enabled = False
        TextBox40.Enabled = False
        TextBox55.Enabled = False
        TextBox65.Enabled = False
        TextBox73.Enabled = False
        TextBox84.Enabled = False
        TextBox95.Enabled = False
        TextBox100.Enabled = False
        TextBox185.Enabled = False
    Else
        TextBox(??).Enabled = True

    End If
```

How to other textboxes to enable True?
I mean
10,25,30,40... 185 are false and all other textboes Enabled true ?

Comment: I think you need consider to redesign your form. Use [DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **find control of type textbox** and assign **default enabled= true** and then write your code to set enabled=false.

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
If c.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) Then
    c.Enabled=true
End If
Next

OR  

Dim allTextBox As New List(Of Control)
For Each c As TextBox In FindControl(allTextBox, Me,GetType(TextBox))
    c.Enabled=true
Next

Public Shared Function FindControl(ByVal list As List(Of Control), ByVal parent As Control, ByVal ctrlType As System.Type) As List(Of Control)
    If parent Is Nothing Then Return list
    If parent.GetType Is ctrlType Then
        list.Add(parent)
    End If
    For Each child As Control In parent.Controls
        FindControl(list, child, ctrlType)
    Next
    Return list
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the forms Controls collection. Something like:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
for each c in me.controls
        if TypeOf c is TextBox then
            dim Textbox as textbox = DirectCast(c, TextBox)
            'Determine state of your textbox here.
            'Perhaps use the TAG property to assign a selectedindex to each textbox
            Textbox.enabled = (Textbox.Tag.ToString() <> i.ToString())
        end if
next
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with two lists:

```
var falseList = new List<ListBox> { TextBox10, TextBox25, TextBox30, ... };
var trueList = new List<ListBox> { TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, ... };
```

Then in each condition block in the **if** enumerate each list and set false:

```
foreach(var box in falseList) box.Enabled = false;

foreach(var box in trueList) box.Enabled = true;
```

Another option is to setup a DataSource with two booleans and set DataBinding on each of the **true** ListBoxes to one of the properties and the other set to the **false** property then setting the found property on on the datasource they all update in one statement.

Note: Sorry it's c# syntax but it's really close to VB.NET.  I just don't know the exact VB syntax

Comment: It's annoying to write TextBox11 12 13 14 15 16 17 and so on

Comment: That was just illustrating a point, how you'd build the list depends on your scenario.  I'd actually strongly recommend a data binding approach as I mentioned. You do still need a way to group controls into ones that are going to be true and false.  If all TRUE  are going to be in a GroupBox you could grab the controls off that and assign the databinding config in a loop of the GroupBox.Controls and same for the other set.  The beauty is you can switch a whole set of controls with a single assignment statement later.